# how to move duplicate json objects array in c#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "country": "China",
            "color" : "Red",
            "pet" : "Cat",
            "name" : "Mark",
            "height_unit_name" : "cm"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "color" : "black",
            "pet" : "dog",
            "name" : "Jane",
            "height_unit_name" : "cm"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to move the duplicate data outside each array and show it once like this...
Like "country" and "height_unit_name", both are same in each array.

```
{
    "country": "China",
    "height_unit_name": "cm",
    "data": [
        {           
            "color": "Red",
            "pet": "Cat",
            "name": "Mark"
        },
        {
            "color": "black",
            "pet": "dog",
            "name": "Jane"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thankyou for your helping

Comment: What type of objects are these? Are they JsonObjects? If so, can you put them in a record that describes them?

Comment: Have you done any attempts at solving it yourself? Would be easier to assist if you have any code already.

Comment: @AoooR No. I got the list from the query. But I don't know know to handle it

Comment: @MarengoHue Yes, I have tried it myself. But still, don't know what to do. As mentioned above, this is the example data that similar to mine that I got from a query. I am not sure do I have to query two times or not

Comment: (sorry for my bad English skill)

Comment: Encapsulate json array traversal into list collection.
Use "list.Distinct().ToList()" to filter list collection elements;

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq for this

```
var jsonArr = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["data"];

List<CountryPets> pets = jsonArr
    .GroupBy(a => new { c = (string)a["country"], h = (string)a["height_unit_name"], })
    .Select(b => new CountryPets
    {
        Country = b.Key.c,
        HeightUnitName = b.Key.h,
        Pets = b.Select(a => a.ToObject<Pet>()).ToList()
    }).ToList();

public partial class CountryPets
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string HeightUnitName { get; set; }
    public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}

public partial class Pet
{
    [JsonProperty("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pet")]
    public string PetType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you actually want to do is:

1. deserialize the JSON in some kind of structured `object`. I've used 'RawData' and `RawItem` in my example.

   ```
         string json = "{    \"data\": [        {            \"country\": \"China\",            \"color\" : \"Red\",            \"pet\" : \"Cat\",            \"name\" : \"Mark\",            \"height_unit_name\" : \"cm\"        },        {            \"country\": \"China\",            \"color\" : \"black\",            \"pet\" : \"dog\",            \"name\" : \"Jane\",            \"height_unit_name\" : \"cm\"        }    ]}";
        RawData rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RawData>(json);
   ```
2. Once you have the raw data as a list you can do a GroupBy. In your case you group by `country` and `color`.

   ```
   List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
   var groupedData = rawData.data.GroupBy(x => new { country = x.country, color = x.color });
   ```
3. Then you create your desired object structure.

   ```
     foreach (var item in groupedData)
     {
         List<Data> data = new List<Data>();

         foreach (var dataItem in item)
         {
             data.Add(new Data { pet = dataItem.pet, name = dataItem.name, height_unit_name = dataItem.height_unit_name });
         }
         items.Add(new Item { country = item.Key.country, color = item.Key.color, data = data });
     }
   ```
4. Serialize the newly created structure.

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items));
   ```

full running example on .net fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/s4Q4LV

and if you are more the java script "i don't give a f*** about type safetey" guy: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8xE4Du